# Servlet java remember URL before going to CAS

Tags: java, servlets, cas

I have a servlet deployed on Jboss AS7 that manages authentication through CAS. So, when a user tries to go to www...../auth/wpm, my auth detects that the user is not authenticated, it goes to my servlet that constructs a followupURL and after authentication redirects him back at the followupURL. Now, the problem is that until now i had a custom authentication in my servlet and it worked because in doGET method i build the followupURL based on what he accessed, but now I have to do this with CAS. The problem is that a user can access /auth/wpm or /auth/htc...etc and they all get into my servlet because auth does that. The problem is that my servlet has CAS filters and after successful authentication, it gets to my servlet **FROM** CAS, and not from what the user tried to access so now I can't create my followupURL. When I'm into doGET method I don't know what the user tried to access, .../wpm or .../htc. What can I do so I know what the user tried to access in my doGET method, after CAS authentication? INFO: I can't use CAS directly on my /wpm or /htc because it has to go through my servlet because I have to create a cookie and I can't make that in /wpm or /htc.
Thank you.

UPDATE: The flow is like this:
.../auth/wpm -> .../myServlet -> .../CAS (for authentication) -> **.../myServlet**. At the end, I need to create followupURL but I don't know ".../auth/wpm" (because it could be .../auth/htc - they all have the same flow)

Comment: if I understand you well, the problem is with the redirecting user to page that he came from to authenticate himself?

Comment: Yes. CAS redirects me to my servlet, but then I can't create the followupURL because it's coming from CAS...

Comment: You can create some bypass like, if you know that user comes from CAS to authenticate, redirect him again after auth to servlet that creates an access for CAS. How your URL looks like? Are you able to tell where your user is in the moment by its parameters?

Comment: It's not coming from CAS to authenticate. It's going to CAS to authenticate and all I'm doing now is redirecting back from where it comes. And it comes from .../myServlet, but I don't know that ".../auth/wpm" he entered.